# What would the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2-y)$ look like?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, elliptic-curves

What would the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2-y)$ look like? And also what would the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^3-x-y^2)$ look like?

These are two sorts of rings I have been curious about.

Comment: The ring in the title of your question is isomorphic to the polynomial ring in one variable, $\mathbb Z[y]$.  The isomorphism sends any polynomial $p(y)\in\mathbb Z[y]$ to the equivalence class in $\mathbb Z[x,y]/(x^2-y)$ of the same polynomial $p(y)$ regarded as an element of $\mathbb Z[x,y]$.  The ring in the body of your question is more complicated.

Comment: In my previous comment, "the isomorphism" should be "an isomorphism" or perhaps "the simplest isomorphism".

Comment: The second one, at least, has a simple description: the (classes of) the monomials $x^iy^j$ with $i\geq0$ and $0\leq j<2$ is a $\mathbb Z$-basis, and it is easy to describe the product of two of these elements. In other words, it contains the ring $\mathbb Z[x]$  and it is a free module of rank $2$ over it (with $1$ and $y$ as basis, for example)